# Unable to add compute nodes to HPC Cluster

Tags: azure, hpc

I am trying to setup HPC cluster environment with Azure VMs as head node and compute nodes.

Head node is working properly. However, when I try to add compute nodes from HPC Cluster Manager of head node, compute nodes don't show up. If I try to open the HPC Cluster Manager from compute nodes, it asks for the head node and when I provide the name of the head node, it fails with the below error.

"*Failed to communicate with remote SDM store. Connection Failed. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.195.15.194:9893*"

All the VM have Windows Server 2012 R2 and they are in the same VNet/Domain.

Any pointers to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The following 2 templates should help you out. Basically a step by step wizard experience.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/create-hpc-cluster-custom-image/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/create-hpc-cluster/